# OpenMP problems with Matlab mex

Tags: c++, matlab, openmp, race-condition, mex

I'm trying to parallelize my C++ mex code using OpenMP. However, it seems like I'm creating a race condition somewhere and my code exits with glibc() detected. What's more interesting is that my code does not exit all the times. Sometimes, it passes through all the iterations of the loop but it fails sometimes (and Matlab crashes). I really couldn't figure out where the code fails. Does anyone have any inputs?

Here is my code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
    int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {


mwIndex *jcUq31;
double *const1;

const1 = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
jcUq31 = mxGetJc(prhs[2]);

/*Assign the constants*/
int nq, npol;
nq=const1[0];
npol=const1[1];

#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp for
    for(int q1=nq/2+1;q1<=nq;q1++){

        int *Uome2, *q2, *pol2, *pol3, *Uq3, *q3, *index2, *index3;
        int num_interactions, q11,j,index1,index;
        int pol1=1;

         Uome2 = (int*)mxMalloc(1*sizeof(int)); //Initialize with just one memory block - will update with mxRealloc
         q2 = (int*)mxMalloc(1*sizeof(int));

         q11=q1-nq/2;

         j=((pol1-1)+(q11-1)*npol)+1; //Column in the interaction matrix - given k(p)

         index1=(pol1-1)*nq+q1;

         num_interactions=jcUq31[j]-jcUq31[j-1];
         mexPrintf("num_interactions %d  thread number %d  q1 %d \n", num_interactions,omp_get_thread_num(),q1);


         Uome2 = (int*)mxRealloc(Uome2, num_interactions*sizeof(int));
         q2 = (int*)mxRealloc(q2, num_interactions*sizeof(int));
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Without even looking in detail, you have race conditions with `Uome2` and `q2`.  You have multiple threads having multiple copies of these pointers, each pointing to address spaces that have different amounts of memory allocated at the different iterations.  Perhaps you should make these pointers declared outside of the loop.  If you want these pointers to be a shared resource where the threads should all threads want to access them, consider using [locks](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#Locks).  However, I don't really get what you're doing here, so I can't comment any further.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the quick response! I have cut down my original code into these lines as I couldn't even get the initializations (Uome2 and q2) to work. I run into glibc detected even if I declare the pointers outside of the loop. About sharing, I don't need the pointers to be shared resource. The processes that will happen inside the loop are independent.

Comment: @PrabhakarMarepalli: you should not be using mx-functions inside the OpenMP block, the MEX API is not thread safe

Comment: @Amro -Thanks for the response. Do you know the alternative to parallelize when I have to use mx-functions?

Comment: @PrabhakarMarepalli: I don't know what your code is doing, but for starters use the regular `malloc` and `realloc` functions instead of the mx-ones where MATLAB manages the memory... And if you have to work on mxArray variables inside a parallel block, retrieve the raw pointers first, and then work on those in any way you want. Just avoid calling MEX API functions from multiple threads without proper use of locks